# How to map column to complex object in SlickGrid

Tags: slickgrid

```
var data = [{"Id":40072,"Id2":40071,"SmDetails":{"Id1":40071,"Id2":40072}}]
```

I want to display `SmDetails.Id1` in a column. How is this possible? I tried:

```
var columns = [{name:'Personnel',field:SmDetails.id1,id:'detailId'}];
```

Please help me
 Please help me

```
**My latest code**
         var data = [{"Id":40072,"Id2":40071,"allocationDetails":{"Id1":40071,"allocationDetails":{"accommodationId":4007}}}]
    var grid;
                var columns = [                                        {name:"Personnel",field:"allocationDetails",fieldIdx:'accommodationId', id:"accommodationId"}];
                var options = {
                     enableCellNavigation: true,
                    enableColumnReorder: false,
                     dataItemColumnValueExtractor:
                                                                function getValue(item, column) { 
                        var values = item[column.field];                             
                      if (column.fieldIdx !== undefined) {
                return values && values[column.fieldIdx];
                } else {
                return values;
                }}};
                var gridData=$scope.Vo;//This return as json format                         
                grid = new Slick.Grid("#testGrid",gridData, columns);
    This is the code tried recently.
```

Comment: try `SmDetails.Id1` (i is in uppercase)

Comment: Yes I tried the same.But it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide a [custom value extractor](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/gh-pages/examples/example-custom-column-value-extractor.html) to tell the grid how to read your object.

```
var options = {
  enableCellNavigation: true,
  enableColumnReorder: false,
  dataItemColumnValueExtractor:
  // Get the item column value using a custom 'fieldIdx' column param
  function getValue(item, column) { 
    var values = item[column.field];
    if (column.fieldIdx !== undefined) {
        return values && values[column.fieldIdx];
    } else {
        return values;
    }
  }
};
```

The column definitions would look like:

```
{
  id: "field1",
  name: "Id1",
  field: "SmDetails",
  fieldIdx: 'Id1'
}, {
  id: "field2",
  name: "Id2",
  field: "SmDetails",
  fieldIdx: 'Id2'
} //... etc
```

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/QQV5J/) for a working example.

Comment: I tried this in my application.But value dispalyed as [object Object].

Comment: Add your latest code to the end of your original post so that I can see how you set it up.

Comment: Please check the latest comments added

Comment: The `allocationDetails` is nested in the data provided in the edit. Is that the proper structure? `allocationDetails:{ allocationDetails:{}}`

Answer (score 0):

try this to convert your `data` into object of single length values ...

```
newData = {};
for(key in data[0]){
    parentKey = key;
    if(typeof(data[0][key]) == "object"){
       childData = data[0][key];
       for(key in childData){
          childKey = key;
          newKey = parentKey+childKey;
          newData[newKey] = childData[childKey];
       }
    } else {
       newData[key] = data[0][key];
      }
}
```

This will convert your `data` object like this

```
newData = {Id: 40072, Id2: 40071, SmDetailsId1: 40071, SmDetailsId2: 40072};
```

Now use this `newData` to map your data items in grid

Answer (score -1):

I find this works well for nested properties, eg:

```
var columns = [
    { id: "someId", name: "Col Name", field: "myRowData.myObj.myProp", width: 40}
..
];

var options {
...
dataItemColumnValueExtractor: function getItemColumnValue(item, column) {
    var val = undefined;
    try {
        val = eval("item." + column.field);
    } catch(e) {
        // ignore
    }
    return val;
    }
};
```